# ReactJs component dynamic data is not prepared into a list

Tags: javascript, react-native, dynamic, react-redux, react-router

I have a ReactJs Component that fetches data from an api and passes it to a Slider component. It seems that when I map over the response data with `.map()`, it does not work but if I call the data directly with array index in the component passed via props, it works.

For example I have two components below, defined as follows.

This is the inner component I to which I will pass the data.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

class HeroAreaSlid extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <li style={{backgroundImage:`url(${this.props.data && this.props.data.backgroundImg !== undefined && this.props.data.backgroundImg})`}}>
          <div className="overlay"></div>
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-md-pull-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 js-fullheight slider-text">
                <div className="slider-text-inner js-fullheight">
                  <div className="desc">
                    <h1>
                    {
                      this.props.data && this.props.data.headerLine !== undefined &&
                      parse(this.props.data.headerLine)
                    }
                    </h1>
                    <p><a className="btn btn-primary btn-learn" href={this.props.data && this.props.data.link !== undefined && this.props.data.link} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    {
                      this.props.data && this.props.data.text !== undefined &&
                      parse(this.props.data.text)
                    }
                    <i className={this.props.data && this.props.data.icon !== undefined && this.props.data.icon}></i></a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li> 
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default HeroAreaSlid;
```

And I call it from this component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import axios from 'axios'; 

import HeroAreaSlid from './hero-area_slide'

class HeroArea extends Component {
  constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
      heroarea_: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
        axios.get("https://sym-api-dev.herokuapp.com/sym-api/me/heroarea")
        .then(response =>{
      this.setState({heroarea_: response.data});
      this.setState({flag: true});
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error);
    })
  } 

  render() {
    let {heroarea_} = this.state; 
    return (
      <>
        <section id="sym-hero" className="js-fullheight" data-section="home">
          <div className="flexslider js-fullheight">
            <ul className="slides">
              <HeroAreaSlid
                 data = {heroarea_[0]}
              />
              <HeroAreaSlid
                data = {heroarea_[1]}
              />
              <HeroAreaSlid
                data = {heroarea_[2]}
              />
            </ul>
          </div>
        </section>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default HeroArea;
```

Above, if I call HeroAreaSlid three times then it works but if I change that block with the  code below, it does not.

```
{
   heroarea_.map(heroarea_inner => {
   <HeroAreaSlid
    data = {heroarea_[0]}
   />
   })
}
```

It's not working. Kindly help me to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR:

Possible bug: You are not returning a component when you map over the returned api data, and always trying to return the first one. You should return a JSX component. Like...

```
// Note: You should add a unique key to your mapped data
{heroarea_.map(heroarea_inner => (
  <HeroAreaSlid key={heroarea_inner.headerLine} data={heroarea_inner} />
))}
```

See live [CodeSandbox for your Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/repro-mapping-over-data-oxsn5?file=/src/App.js) here

---

@Mahesh, when you map over an array, you should always return something from your callback function.

- React needs an element to render but your arrow function does not return anything. See <kbd>Comment 1</kbd>.
- When mapping over an array, the callback is passed the (element, index) of that item in the array. So you assign your element in the iteration as `heroarea_inner` but you don't use it anywhere, instead directly calling the first item in your array every time with `heroarea_[0]`. All the list items will eventually be identical to the first one. See <kbd>Comment 2</kbd>.
- For performance when re-rendering, it's a great idea to pass a unique [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) to the items in a list of similar components. See <kbd>Comment 3</kbd>.

```
{
   heroarea_.map(heroarea_inner => { 
   // 1. This component is not being returned.
   <HeroAreaSlid
     data = {heroarea_[0]} // 2. This always returns the 1st item. Use heroarea_inner
     key={unqueItem} // 3. Use a unique item in you heroarea_inner 
   />
   })
}
```

You can read about [.map() here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and see how it's used to render react lists [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Answer (score 0):

I Have figure out the solution be like before rendering data i have make pass dummy data in render to create that component & when data comes it will pass the actual data from api

as render code as follows

```
 render() {
        let {heroarea_} = this.state; 
        console.log("heroarea_1 :: "+heroarea_);

        const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
        const doubled = numbers.map((number) => number * 2);
        return (
          <>
            <section id="sym-hero" className="js-fullheight" data-section="home">
              <div className="flexslider js-fullheight">
                <ul className="slides">
                {console.log("heroarea_2 :: "+heroarea_)}
                {!heroarea_.length && this.setState({heroarea_:doubled})}
                {console.log("heroarea_3 :: "+heroarea_)}
                {
                  heroarea_.map(heroarea_inner => 
                    <HeroAreaSlid data = {heroarea_inner}/>
                  )
                }
                </ul>
              </div>
            </section>
          </>
        );
      }
```